# How to filter out things on google map by drawing any shape on it using ReacJS or JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to draw any shapes on google map and filter out things using Reactjs or JS like this website 'https://www.homely.com.au/buy/map/-33.8118/151.0306/14' does?

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS has a useful map library for Google Maps. We use it in an enterprise environment.

https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

**EDIT:**

Anything contained inside the `GoogleMapReact` component can take a lat/lng attribute.

Like so:

```
<GoogleMapReact ...>
    <myCustomComponent
        lat={0.0}
        lng={0.0}
    />
<GoogleMapReact />
```

Comment: Thank you. I also use this library, but how to draw things on the map like the website I list above?

Comment: @WayneLi I have edited the question with an answer to your comment.